# Swift tableViews send array of images to collectionView using parse

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

so this is my first post here I've been developing in swift for a few months now and just can't work my way around this problem.

I have tried explaining what I need help with in my image.

If i click on tableview row 1 i want send an array of 30-70 images to a collection view and this kinda works, except it shows same images on all rows, tableview row 2 -3 -4.
[image of collectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQLGJ.png)
Please take a look at this link for my parse Database
[parse database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4olPa.png)

I am more than happy to share on bitbucket.

---

```
    //Here goes the TableView
```

---

```
import UIKit
import Parse
```

class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

```
var selectedRow:PFUser?

var userids = [""]
var wonk = ["wonk"]
var slagtHuset = ["slagtHuset"]
var Adelgatan = ["Adelgatan"]


// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "crowd"
    self.textKey = "cellTitle"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
```

//      self.objectsPerPage = 3
    }

```
// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "crowd")
    query.orderByDescending("cellTitle")

    // Only retrieve the last ten
    query.limit = 10
    return query
}

//override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as! CustomTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    }
    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if let nameEnglish = object?["cellTitle"] as? String {
        cell.customNameEnglish.text = nameEnglish
    }

    // Display flag image
    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
    cell.customFlag.image = initialThumbnail
    if let thumbnail = object?["crowdImage"] as? PFFile {
        cell.customFlag.file = thumbnail
        cell.customFlag.loadInBackground()
    }

    return cell
}

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

    // Pass the selected object to the destination view controller.
    if let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)
        detailScene.currentObject = objects?[row] as? PFObject
        //detailScene.currentObject = [Adelgatan, slagtHuset]
```

//       NSIndexPath *indexPath=[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
 //       DOG *details= (DOG*)segue.destinationViewController;

//       PFObject *object=[self.typeDog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];
 //       details.stringdata=[object objectForKey:@"username"];

```
    // pass whatever data you want to display in the collection view as an array here.
```

//     details.array = ...

```
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    // Refresh the table to ensure any data changes are displayed
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

---

Here is code for detailView(collectionView)

---

```
    import UIKit
```

var countries = PFObject

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

```
// Container to store the view table selected object
var currentObject : PFObject?

var wonk = ["wonk"]
var slagtHuset = ["slagtHuset"]
var Adelgatan = ["Adelgatan"]
```

//    var clubs = [slagtHuset, Adelgatan, wonk]

```
// Some text fields
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var flag: PFImageView!      

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Resize size of collection view items in grid so that we achieve 3 boxes across
    let cellWidth = ((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width) - 3 - 3 ) / 2
    let cellHeight = ((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width) - 4 - 3 ) / 2
    let cellLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    cellLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
}


func loadCollectionViewData() {



    // Build a parse query object

    var query = PFQuery(className:"crowd")
    //more specs    query.whereKey("currencyCode", equalTo:"EUR")
    query.orderByAscending("objectId")

    // Fetch data from the parse platform
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // The find succeeded now rocess the found objects into the countries array
        if error == nil {

            // Clear existing country data
            countries.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            // Add country objects to our array
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                countries = Array(objects.generate())
            }

            // reload our data into the collection view
            self.collectionView.reloadData()

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(countries)
    return countries.count

}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    // Display "initial" flag image
    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
    cell.cellImage.image = initialThumbnail


    // Here is my problem where i only load image from Adelgatan
    // Fetch final flag image - if it exists
    if let value = countries[indexPath.row]["Adelgatan"] as? PFFile {
        let finalImage = countries[indexPath.row]["Adelgatan"] as? PFFile
        finalImage!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                }
         }
        }
    }

    return cell
```